# Angular Crashing Browser in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, webforms

I'm having a strange issue with Angular crashing my browser which I can't figure out how to get around.  I have a legacy ASP.NET Web Forms project. I was asked to add a new feature that lives in its own tab. The back end developer created a RESTful API for me to get and post from. However with the header and footer still living in Web Forms I still needed to reference the master page. I developed the prototype for this app on my Mac using Sublime Text and it works perfectly, all I'm trying to do is integrate it into the WebForms project.

What we did is, creat a new master page called TST.master (the name of the new feature) inside TST.master is all the webforms code for the header and the footer. in the `<head>` tag is where all the Angular scripts library scripts live.

Inside the project there is a TST folder with a index.asp file that references the TST.master page. In the index.asp file is a div with an ng-app. Then nested inside that is an empty div with an ng-view.

At the bottom of the index.aspx is all the app.js, controllers.js, services.js etc tags.

With the navigation being done in webforms, header buttons for my section point to index.asp with /#/ after for the routing. so index.aspx/#/section1 index.aspx/#/section2 etc etc.

When I load up the main web forms app it loads fine. But when I navigate to the angular section of the app the browser locks up. I can't load up the console because the browser is frozen.

However if I comment out the ng-view or the script tag with angular.js it freezes up. I have no idea whats happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a runnable sample?

Comment: Usually browser crashes when there is situation when it can't handle, for example infinite loop or stack overflow. My recommendation is to comment everything and then uncomment piece by piece to see which part causes this crashed.

Comment: So after some experimentation it seems its definitely due to the routing. It appears that the contents of the master page are being rendered normally, then angular is also trying to render the master pages header and footer inside the ng-view over and over which is causing the crash. 

The only slightly pecular thing we're doing is. Angular's routing is based off the URL yet because this app is mainly a webforms app we had to do some trickery.

Comment: The routing for the pages in angular looks like this 

localhost:64126/app/tst/index.aspx/#/section1

where as other sections of the app the url looks like 

localhost:64126/app/somefolder/somesection_home.aspx

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, it was a simple fix. all I had to do was add a `../` in front of the routing `templateUrl:` due to the new file structure inside of the .net app. Really interesting that it caused the asp.net webforms to infinite loop inside the view though.

Comment: I was having a problem where my `ng-app` was looping continuously on staging but not locally; turns out I was having a similar problem where my partial wasn't getting called on Heroku because we were storing on S3 and I wasn't giving it the right URL. Thanks for posting this up!